# How do i make the Subtotal kolom that make u sum off the values kolom

Tags: sql, time, sql-order-by, rollup, subtotal

How do i make the Subtotal kolom that make u sum off the values kolom.

Day 1 = 5 Day2 = 3  subtotal = 8 etc. etc.

| Date | Value | Subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 5 | 5 |
| 03-02-2021 | 3 | 8 |
| 05-03-2021 | 7 | 15 |

I use this query for the value p day

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DatabaseTimestamp AS float)) AS DATETIME) AS time, Vogel AS metric, SUM(paren) AS valeu
FROM dbo.Vondsten AS A
WHERE (ISNULL(geannuleerd, 0) = 0) AND (sid IN (63)) AND (hoofdvondstid = - 1) AND (ISNULL(predatieid, 0) < 1) AND (Tag3 NOT IN (1, 2, 4)) AND (wachtid > 0) AND (wachtid < 118)
GROUP BY CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DatabaseTimestamp AS float)) AS DATETIME), Vogel
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would appear to be:

```
SUM(SUM(paren)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(DatabaseTimestamp))
```

Your code for extracting the date looks needless complicated.  But without a database tag, sample data, or explanation, it is hard to make any recommendations.